# The differences between "make a living" and "earn a living"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Who can say the differences between them?

Answer (score 5):

For all intents and purposes, *make a living* and *earn a living* are identical in meaning. There is a *very* slight difference in register, in that *make* is a teeny-tiny bit more informal than *earn*, but it's such a small difference that it can be ignored in most situations. There's also an almost-infinitesimal difference in connotation: using "make" rather than "earn" can imply that you're not working "in your field". For example, if someone with a degree in art history had a job at a museum, they'd be more likely to call it "earning a living", whereas if the same art history graduate had a job at Walmart, they'd be more likely to call it "making a living".<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1<sub>Well, OK, if they're really working at Walmart they'd actually be more likely to call it "just barely scraping by", but that's a different subject.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing but *earn a living* specifies **how** the action happens.

Comment: Can you use each in a sentence to illustrate this difference?

Comment: You could say "I make a living as a painter" or "I earn a living as a painter", about equivalent. Today, "earn" might be a bit more formal, "make" colloquial.

Comment: What do you mean that *earn a living* specifies *how* the action happens? It's no more specific than *make a living*.